# November 25th 2011 partial solar eclipse visibility from Christchurch, New Zealand

Tags: astronomy, eclipse

Where can I find a site that will give me an indication of coverage for the [November 25th 2011 partial solar eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_eclipse_of_November_25,_2011) as viewed from [Christchurch, New Zealand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christchurch) tonight, as well as local times for the stages of the event?

Planning on viewing from 43.780 S, 172.660 E (just east of [Lake Ellesmere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Ellesmere_/_Te_Waihora), I will be looking west over the lake) in the hope of getting a reflection photograph over the lake, if the water is still enough, unless anyone can see any flaw in this plan.

**UPDATE**

Success.  Despite the national media reporting it at 7.30pm, they had the wrong time too!  Was an hour out, and just before sunset.  However it was better than an hour earlier, if we'd missed it!  One of my shots below:

[image]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_eclipse_of_November_25,_2011

Comment: yeah I can also use Wiki :)  Sadly it is nowhere near detailed enough for local readings - watch the animation, and you'll see it starts at different places at different times.  I want to find the calculations for Christchurch...

Comment: Yeah, since it was Thanksgiving in the US, I didn't have time for a real answer, but I thought it might help someone get started.

Comment: So, did you see anything?  I think that's the real question at this point. :)

Comment: Success! Had to chase to keep ahead of the clouds, but got a shot.  Will update question with my photo.

Comment: Great picture! It reminds me of sunrise views of transits of Mercury and Venus I observed a few years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RASC Observer's Handbook contains detailed predictions for Christchurch.  In UT eclipse begins at 7:07, max eclipse at 7:42. Magnitude of eclipse 0.278, obscuration 0.170.  Slightly more eclipse (0.306) in Dunedin.  These extreme partial eclipses aren't of much interest to astronomers, and most ordinary people would hardly notice such a slight covering of the Sun.

My article shows the coverage as seen from Dunedin, as well as Cape Town, Hobart and the South Pole:

http://www.space.com/13725-partial-solar-eclipse-viewing-tips.html

Comment: Would be worth mentioning that that time is UTC and not local, which is 13 hours head, so started at 8.07pm.  Photo updated in question - it was still worth a look! :)

Answer (score 5):

A great site for planning eclipse [viewing is one hosted by NASA](http://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/eclipse.html).  Not only does it give you information on how the eclipse will look, but it tracks information for any future eclipses.  [This figure gives a more detailed map](http://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/OH/OHfigures/OH2011-Fig05.pdf).  Looks like you just barely get the tail end of it.

[image: NASA Eclipse Image]

Perhaps you can plan future eclipse viewing as you peruse that NASA site and be more prepared.

Comment: Thanks, I've used it before, but it still doesn't offer a calculator for lat/long.  I know I've seen one before, to calculate how much you'll see, what %, and for how long.  I've already got my accommodation and flights lined up for the November 2012 total, so well prepared for that ;)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you'll get a very partial solar eclipse that starts at 7:08PM local time.  Sunset with a flat horizon is 7:43 local time, during which it will still be in eclipse, a little more than half-way through.  The amount of eclipse is <25%, though (guesstimating, it looks to be around 15% during maximum from that lat/lon).

Comment: We're 13 ahead of GMT :)

Comment: Alright, answer is corrected.  I also had your longitude as W instead of E.  That's why Starry Night did +11 instead of +13.

Comment: Not quite, not sure what's with the calculations, as the national news site had those times too.  However it didn't start until 8.07, and peaked about 40 minutes later.  See updated question with my photo ;)  And your percentage looks pretty good for a 'guesstimate' ;)